# Change data in DetailViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, master-detail

Im trying to create a master-DetailView application and I'm stuck at the moment, Im trying to create the template for my data . For example i would like to have an array that will control on the data  (a label for example / an image ) manually and change by the indexPath,So every cell will have a different dat presented on,
Here i connected all the labels and images i want to control their data:

```
  class BarProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController,MKMapViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var Distance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var headerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var Address: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ProfileMapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet var BarNameLBL: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var streetNameLBL: UILabel!

    var photos = ["Shalvata cover","litzmancover"]
    var barName = String()
    var barImage = UIImage()
    var streetName = String()
    var images: [UIImage] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        ///headerImage.image = barImage
        BarNameLBL.text = barName
        streetNameLBL.text = streetName
        navigationItem.title = barName
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let item = photos[indexPath.row]
        headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(item).png")
    }
```

Comment: Just to get it right: You want to update UI elements with different content according to the item you select in the table view?

Comment: Exactly ! And i want to control the content it self with an array like  var photos = ["day","night"] and it will change the images with these names @lufritz

Comment: @lufritz can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var photos = ["day","night"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = photos[indexPath.row]
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(item).png")
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Its working partially it shows the same picture no mattar what cell i tap

Comment: Where is `headerImage` located in your view hierarchy? Is it a connection to a `UIImageView` inside a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: UITableViewCell>ContentView>HeaderImage! so yea

Comment: Ok, that doesn't work. Set your connections in a UITableViewCell subclass and change the content by `tableView.reloadData()` ... Please read a guide (e.g. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/). I would be too much to explain here.

Comment: Here another tutorial in swift.
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ That's everything i can do for you.